# Splitting a string into multiple int form using indexOf()

Tags: java, string, indexing

This is my first post so go easy on me. This IS a homework question, but I have spent about 7 hours working through various means to complete this goal and have had no success. I am building various methods for an assignment, and I need to figure out how to split a `String` into several `int` variables.

Ex: given the `String` "100 200 300" I need to change it to three `int` of `100`, `200`, `300`. I have to use `indexOf()`, and cannot use `split()` or arrays.

```
    String scores="100 200 300";
    int n=scores.indexOf(" ");
    String sub=scores.substring(0,n);
    Integer.parseInt(sub);
```

This lets me get the first string "100" and parse it. However, I do not know how to continue the code so it will get the next ones. For my method, I will need the new `int` variables for later arguments.

EDIT: I think I need to use a `for` loop: something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<=scores.length; i++)
{//I do not know what to put here}
```

Comment: Umm..how do you repeat things in programming?..A loop?

Comment: In general, you might also consider String.split().  For example: `String[] sArray = scores.split (" "); int[] iArray[sArray.length]; for (int i=0; i < sArray.length; i++) iArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(sArray[i]);`

Comment: @FoggyDay unfortunately split not allowed

Comment: ya can't use split()

Comment: @JoeHeiler arraylist allowed ??

Comment: I'm thinking I need a for loop, maybe for(int i=0, i<=scores.length,i++)

Comment: no I cannot use array @getlost

Comment: @JoeHeiler can you grantee that numbers have length 3

Comment: @getlost no I cannot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe, indexOf() is overloaded, check out this version:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

1. a loop;
2. being able to run `indexOf()` from where it left off (hint: read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String scores = "100 200 300";
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int n = 0;
        while (n != -1) {
            String sub = "";
            n = scores.indexOf(" ");
            if (n != -1) {
                sub = scores.substring(0, n);
                scores = scores.substring((n + 1));
            } else {
                sub = scores;
            }
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(sub));
        }
        for (int i : numbers) {
            System.out.println("" + i);
        }
    }
```

Try something like this to loop through and add numbers to arraylist.  The arraylist numbers will contain all your numbers.

Comment: This looks a lot like what I need, but can't use array

Comment: What are you trying to do with the int's after you have parsed them?

Comment: I need to add them and compare to another variable, also need to compare the total number of ints to a third variable

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    String scores="100 200 300";
    int offset = 0;
    int space;
    int score;

    scores = scores.trim(); //clean the string

    do
    {
        space= scores.indexOf(" ", offset);
        if(space > -1)
        {
            score = Integer.parseInt(scores.substring(offset , space)); 
        }
        else
        {
            score = Integer.parseInt(scores.substring(offset));     
        }

        System.out.println(score);  
        offset = space + 1;

    }while(space > -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'n' variable is the important part. You get your first String by slicing from 0 to 'n', so your next string starts not at 0, but at 
n + " ".size()

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is what I have come up with: 
Since I needed to compare the newly parsed `ints` with a different variable, as well as ensure that the amount of `ints` was equal to a different variable, I created this `while` loop:

```
public boolean isValid()
{
int index=0;
int initialindex=0;
int ntotal=0;
int ncount=0;
boolean flag=false;
while (index!=-1)
{
    index=scores.indexOf(" ");
    String temp=scores.substring(initialindex,index);
    int num=Integer.parseInt(temp);
    ntotal+=num;
    ncount++;
    initialindex=index;
}
 if (ntotal==total && ncount==count)
{
    flag=true;
}
return flag;
}
```